# Regex expression with leading zero

Tags: regex

I'm rather new to regex expressions and need help with a simple expression.  I'm using Pentaho for ETL (Replace in String transformation) and I have column values that I need to add leading zeros to and parse out text as part of the database import.  So far I have been unable to add the leading zero.

The column is called **Region** and the values are **"region 8"**, **"region 10"**, **"region 11"**.  My regex expression is ['Region'] which will eliminate the region text but produces results = "8", "10", "11".  I need values to produce "08", "10", "11". So all the single digit numbers must have leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their response.  My solution was to replace the whole word "Region" with 0 using a regex expression (replace in string transformation).  I added a java expression transformation to eliminate the leading zero before the digits.  Initial results after expr - 012, 06, etc., having a length of 2 and 3 depending.  I only needed the last two digits and retrieved those through a javascript transformation.                                                                                                 var str = REGION_b;
var n =str.slice(-2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a look ahead in two steps:

```
Regex 1:   region (?=\d\D)
Replace 1: 0

Regex 2:   region (?=\d\d)
Replace 2: (nothing)
```

A look ahead is non-consuming, so you don't have to bother with back references etc.

Comment: this was the closest solution but still is not quite doing what I need it to do.  Regex 1 does not add a zero to a single digit and regex 2 will parse out "region" but results are Region 1, Region 6 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/^region[0-9][0-9]$/region
s/^region\([1-9]\)$/region0\1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use backreferences and multiple checks but it is possible. Here is an example using JavaScript:

```
"region 8".replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1');
//returns "08"

"region 18".replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1');
//returns "18"

"region 188".replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1');
//returns "188"
```

The first step is to remove all non-digit characters `.replace(/\D/g, '')` and replace any single digits with a 0 followed by itself. You can do this using a backreference (`$1`): `.replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1')`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript example using an anonymous function to check the value of the captured number and add a `0` to the return value if it is < 10. eg:

```
column = "region 8";

column.replace(/region (\d+)/, function(s, p1){return parseInt(p1) < 10 ? '0' + p1 : p1});
```

The function takes the whole matched string `s` and the captured part `p1` as parameters

Answer (score 0):

A perl way to do it:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/\D+//g;
    printf("%02d\n", $_);
}

__DATA__
region 8
region 10
region 11
```

**output:**

```
08
10
11
```